# How to determine default enabled permissions for for pre-installed applications?

Tags: security, permissions, privacy, google-apps, bloatware

Many Android apps that are pre-installed by manufacturers have extensive and intrusive requested permissions.

When looking at the permissions of each app via `Settings > Apps`, some of the permissions are allowed by default, while others are not allowed.

How does one determine which of the requested permissions were allowed by default on a non-rooted device?

Comment: Related: [Listing permissions of Android application via adb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21091022/295004)

Comment: You may find my app helpful: https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thank you Irfan, I'll hoping to have time to take a look.